# How do you write your graphql mutations testable in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql, graphql-ruby

When you create a mutation, you usually follow this guide and create one with `GraphQL::Relay::Mutation.define`
http://graphql-ruby.org/relay/mutations.html

I found this website, and this explains another approach to create a mutation by using `GraphQL::Function`
https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-ruby/3-mutations/
http://graphql-ruby.org/fields/function.html

`GraphQL::Function` looks so much easier to test, but I am not sure if I will lose some functionalities compared to a mutation defined by `GraphQL::Relay::Mutation.define`.

Are there any differences when to use from the client side?

Comment: You could test the `resolve` of your mutation's field and test the impact of the resolved mutation. Example: `YourMutationRoot.fields['updateCurrentUser'].resolve(nil, input, context)` where you manually set the provided input as a hash and same for context

Answer (score 0):

i think this way is more easy, in mutation_type.rb

```
Types::MutationType = GraphQL::ObjectType.define do
  name "Mutation"

  field :yourMutation, yourType do
    argument :field, type_of_field
    resolve -> (obj, args, ctx){
      #do whatever you want
  }
```